# how to store a uint32_t in a plist

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, uint32

I have a plist where I would like to save a some response details from my server too, however the variables are of type uint32_t and plists do not have a whole lot of type options to choose from other than, number - string - array - dictionary etc.

so what is the best course of action? conversion? if so how would I go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ NSNumber numberWithInt: value ]
```

Answer (score 4):

When decoding, `integer` will automatically choose the best size, be it 32 or 64 bits. When encoding, you should specifically call `[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt: ...]` or a similar method to create an `NSNumber` of the right size. However, it will be encoded as `integer` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

how to write an integer to a plist can be found here: http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/